# $g(\alpha )=f(\alpha )$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Can anyone help me prove the following?

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$ and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. If $f$ is a linear functional on $W$ , prove there is a linear functional $g$ on $V$ such that $g(\alpha ) = f(\alpha )$ for each $\alpha$ in the subspace $W$.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Choose a basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ for $W$ and extend it to a basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_k, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$. Let $g \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be the unique linear map satisfying

$$ g(v_i) = \begin{cases} f(v_i) & 1 \leq i \leq k, \\ 0 & k + 1 \leq i \leq n. \end{cases} $$

Comment: Had I given 1 instead of 0 for $k+1\le i \le n$ what would have been the problem?

Comment: There wouldn't be any problem. If $\dim W < \dim V$, there are many possible extensions of $f$ to $V$.

Comment: @ levap : I guessed as much... But thanks for the confirmation